# Looking for explanation for a stack corruption bug

Tags: c++, c++11, optimization, visual-studio-2017, stack-corruption

The following problem is distilled from a huge project and the most minimal example of the problem I was able to come up with.

I know, deriving from `std::string` is bad, and it already is changed in our code base, but I am trying to understand what is happening under the hood here.

The code crashes on Visual C++ 2017

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017 
Version 15.2 (26430.14) Release
Visual C++ 2017   00369-60000-00001-AA257
```

in release-mode only (with speed optimization). It does not crash in release-mode without speed optimization.

```
#include <string>
#include <string_view>
#include <vector>

struct my_string : public std::string
{
    __declspec(noinline)
        my_string::my_string( const std::string_view& str ) :
        std::string( str.data(), str.size() )
    {}

    template <typename T>
    my_string& arg( T )
    {
        return *this;
    }
};

struct my_string_view : public std::string_view
{
    my_string_view( const std::string_view::value_type* val ) :
        std::string_view( val ) {}

    template <typename... PARAMS>
    my_string arg( PARAMS&&... prms ) {
        return my_string( *this ).arg( std::forward<PARAMS>( prms )... );
    }
};

template <typename T>
struct basic_color
{
    T r, g, b, a;

    basic_color() : r( 0 ), g( 0 ), b( 0 ), a( 255 ) {}

    template <typename U>
    explicit basic_color( const basic_color<U>& c ) :
        r( c.r ), g( c.g ), b( c.b ), a( c.a )
    {}
};

using color = basic_color<std::uint8_t>;
using float_color = basic_color<float>;

__declspec(noinline)
void change_float_color( float_color& color )
{
    color.r = 0.1f;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<float_color> colors = { {} };
    float sum = 0;
    for ( std::uint32_t i = 0; i < 1; ++i )
    {
        float_color fc;
        change_float_color( fc );
        color c( fc );
        std::vector<std::string> msgs;
        msgs.push_back( my_string_view( "" ).arg( c.r ) );
        msgs.push_back( my_string_view( "" ).arg( c.g ) );
        sum += fc.b - colors[i].b;
    }
    return static_cast<int>(sqrt( sum ));
}
```

The error in Visual Studio is this (have a look at the broken sizes of `msgs` and `colors` at the bottom):

[image]

My guess is that the call of `std::vector<std::string>::push_back(std::string&&)` with a `my_string` is problematic (slicing-like behavior). But how can this corrupt the stack (or the stack pointer)?

Does anybody have an idea what could be happening here or how I can find out?

[Here](http://daiw.de/share/so/HWC_crash_minimal_example.zip) is my project in case anyone is interested in reproducing the problem.

Comment: Use the debugger, a data breakpoint is the weapon of choice here.

Comment: "since std::string does not have a virtual destructor, the r-values given to push_back are sliced. " Slicing has nothing to do with having a virtual destructor. The values will be sliced regardless. "Thus the destructor of the derived class (my_string) is never called, some trash remains on the stack" This makes no sense whatsoever. `sizeof(my_string) == sizeof(std::string)` This doesn't make one bit of a difference. "have a look at the broken sizes" The compiler is free to do whatever it wants with these object as they will never be used again.

Comment: > My first guess was that since std::string does not have a virtual destructor, the r-values given to push_back are sliced. Thus the destructor of the derived class (my_string) is never called < Memory allocated (stack in this case) for the class is released regardless of whether destructor is called or not. Moreover, `~my_string` **is** called, because slicing occurs when `my_string` is copied into `std::string`, and original string is not, and cannot be, sliced.

Comment: What about line 40 and 42 on your screenshot? You pas fc, which is basic_color<float>, to the explicit constructor of c, which is basic_color<uint8_t>. As a result, there is an attempt to cast float to uint8_t. Can you get away with that?

Comment: @HansPassant: I tried, but it looks like it is never written to the memory locations of the variables (the data breakpoints do not trigger). Is it possible that the stack-pointer is just off and thus the variable content is displayed incorrectly in the debugger?

Comment: @n.m.: OK, I think I understand. What is something that the compiler could do with the object that causes the crash?

Comment: @Hedede: I don't think `my_string` is copied into `std::string` since the r-value version of `push_back` is called in this situation.

Comment: @KjMag: This `static_cast` simply rounds down the float to the next `std::uint8_t`. This may not be very useful but should not cause a stack corruption.

Comment: @TobiasHermann `std::string(std::string&&)` gets called in that case. That doesn't change the fact that slicing doesn't affect stack whatsoever.

Comment: @TobiasHermann I can't reproduce your problem with code you provided.

Comment: @Hedede: OK, I understand. Now I'm even more interested in learning what does affect the the stack (or stack pointer). Here is my project for you to download. I hope you can reproduce the problem with it: http://daiw.de/share/so/HWC_crash_minimal_example.zip

Comment: I have no idea what could be causing this. I was able to reproduce the crash with gcc, then do the same with a much simpler example, but now I think the gcc might have a totally different problem. Here's the simple example: https://pastebin.com/pym5Mk91 It crashes when compiled on cygwin with -std=c++11 (and any other std++xx, but not gnu++xx). I cannot reproduce this with online Microsoft compilers (I cannot install VS>10 on my machine). Can you reproduce this with an online compiler?

Comment: @n.m. Sorry, I am unable to reproduce it with another compiler. Regarding online compilers, in my Visual C++ 2017 it only crashes when the destructor of `my_string` is defined in `my_string.cpp`. It does not crash if is defined in the `my_string.h`. So visibility of the definition seems to affect the problem, and thus copying everything into one cpp file to an online compiler might show a different result.

Comment: If this is indeed the case then you have discovered an incredibly silly bug in VC++. I find it hard to believe because after the preprocessing there are no more header or source files and the compiler shouldn't even be able to tell.

Comment: @n.m. After preprocessing the source files still are different compilation units and only get combined by the linker. But now I was able to reproduce it all in one single source file by disallowing inlining for some more functions. I edited my question accordingly.

Comment: lol I tried reproducing this in MSVS 2013. derp

Comment: So this depends on what exactly you allow to be inlined. Looks like a compiler bug to me. I cannot find any trace of UB here.

Comment: Same here. Might have to throw it to VS devs and cross your fingers _really_ tightly

Comment: OK, thank you all. I just posted the problem here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b40ebfa9-9fdb-44f9-a778-6c7e24e1c2e4/stack-corrupting-due-to-a-bug-in-the-compileroptimizer?forum=vcgeneral

Comment: what is the line `sum += fc.b - colors[i].b` meant to do if colors was initialised with {} ?

Comment: @Mic: The default constructor of `basic_color` initializes it with `0,0,0,255`, and `colors.size() == 1`, so the line you mention should not be a problem.

Comment: @tobias thanks, I see now it's initilized with {{}} not {} :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it is a compiler bug.

Here's what I see from the disassembly: upon `main()` entry, `esp` is saved into `ebx`. At the end, `esp` is restored from `ebx`. However, in the middle (after calling `std::_Destroy_range1`) `ebx` value is overwritten with something else. So, at the end, the `ret` instruction uses a bogus `esp` value, and jumps to an invalid place.

So, actually, the stack isn't corrupted (this bug cannot be catched with data breakpoints as Hans suggested), but the stack pointer is.

Comment: Thanks for reproducing the problem. I hope [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b40ebfa9-9fdb-44f9-a778-6c7e24e1c2e4/stack-corrupting-due-to-a-bug-in-the-compileroptimizer?forum=vcgeneral) was the correct place on MSDN to post the problem. Anyway I will check if the problem is gone with the official release of the next compiler update.

Comment: @Tobias: [vcblog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/) suggests to report bugs using the [Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio) website. I agree with your comment: this bug is fragile, we can only be sure it is fixed if a VS developer says "yes, I've analyzed the problem, and fixed it"

Comment: OK, [done](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback/Details/3136753). Thanks again.